# Oracle table entries lost.

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

Yesterday I installed Oracle 11g & Oracle Data Access. With the installed sql*plus console I used `/nolog` and the  `connect / as SYSDBA`, then I created a few users and grand them privilegs.
I created a table and insert some values. After closing and reopening the console, the table exists but the entries are lost.
I also tried to login in as an user and created a table... but after restart the entries are lost again.
Could it be that the enviroment variable is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like John said, use the [`commit;` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_4010.htm) to make your changes permanent.

Comment: May I ask, how i implement a table like this one:                                     **SQL> desc car.type;
 var1 NUMBER(10)
 var2 VARCHAR2(2)**                                                        Is it a table in a table?

Comment: No clue - you should probably open a new question for this.